# many local variables declaration vs one global?

Tags: javascript, performance, global-variables, scope, local

i'm just new javascript biginner, 
If i need to reuse many times (lets say 20 times) the same variable, from a performance point of view,
should i declare it one time as global , or declare it many times in each function context in local scope ( as i heard about ) ?

whats case bellow is better ?

**caseA :**

```
var myvar = document.getElementById('case'); //global

function one(){
myvar.innerHTML = 'newb';
...
}
function two(){
myvar.value = '3';
...
}
```

**caseB :**

```
function one(){
var myvar = document.getElementById('case'); //local
myvar.innerHTML = 'newb';
...
}
function two(){
var myvar = document.getElementById('case'); //lobal 
myvar.value = '3';
...
}
```

**caseC :**

```
var myvar = document.getElementById('case'); //global

function one(){
var myvar = document.getElementById('case'); //local
myvar.innerHTML = 'newb';
...
}
function two(){
var myvar = document.getElementById('case'); //lobal 
myvar.value = '3';
...
}
```

thx for advises,
gui

Comment: CaseA because you should only select an element once. In the other cases it will need to traverse the DOM to find an element with id `case` each time `one` and `two` are called.

Comment: As @DavidSherret said. And you should not use caseC at all. It gives no error, but with much code you become confused about the var names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap case A inside a closure

```
(function() {
  var myvar = document.getElementById('case');

  function one(){
    myvar.innerHTML = 'newb';
    ...
  }

  function two(){
    myvar.value = '3';
    ...
  }
})()
```

now nothing is in the global scope but you only access the DOM once.

Comment: could i use myvar outside this anonyme function, if not should i putt all my script in this anonyme function ?

Comment: @albator You can't use it outside, it's private to this IIFE (immediately invoked function expression). And putting all code in an IIFE would work, but it's not the way you should go.

Comment: so i can safely put all my page code in the anonyme function and invoke it immediately ?!

Comment: @albator You can. But with too much nested functions you easiely run into scope- or context-issues.

Comment: can i add some  myvar.addEventListener("click",function()
    {});   in this closure too ?!

Comment: @a You can. Inside an IIFE and also with your caseA.

Comment: @Martin Ernst thanks i believe i understand , so it should smarter to decompose my code in differents closures to not enlarge each local scope, is it right?

Answer (score 1):

The case A must be the best, or if you like object oriented programming you can do :

```
function MyClass() {
    this.element = document.getElementById('case');

    this.one = function() {
        this.element.innerHTML = 'newb';
    }
    this.two = function() {
        this.element.value = '3';
    }

    return this;
}

var myCls = new MyClass();
myCls.one();
myCls.two();
```

Comment: is it any advantage to use objet oriented instead of an anonyme function ?!

Comment: JavaScript core itself use object oriented programming, it's more cleaner and easier to debug, it avoid variables conflits too.
They are pro and cons, and it depends why-when-where you're code will be used.